# Does convergence in probability of $X-Y$ and convergence in distribution of $X$ imply convergence in distribution of $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to learn about the asymptotic properties of random variables. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that

$$\sqrt{n}X \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2)$$

$$\sqrt{n}(X-Y) \xrightarrow{p} 0$$

Can we conclude that $\sqrt{n}Y \xrightarrow{d} N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_n\to A$ in distribution and $B_n\to 0$ in probability, then [$A_n+B_n\to A$ in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667695/proof-of-the-first-equation-of-slutskys-theorem).

Use this with $A_n=\sqrt nX_n$, $A$ having a centered normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ and $B_n=\sqrt n\left(Y_n-X_n\right)$.